# How to create global, instance based objects from local scope?

Tags: javascript

I have a single global object I use.  I know the cons of using global objects but in this case I want to use it.

I call this global object the object pipe b.c. it branches my models to my controller and vice versa...maybe should have called it object branch...anyways...

The mistake I made is that I thought I only had one model running at any given time...but I don't, there are multiple.

Hence I can't use a single static implementation, I need and instance based one, one global object pipe per each model running.

Here is the static versions.  MC stands for Model/Controller.

```
/********************************************************************************************
 *
 * MC - Model/Controller Types
 *
 *******************************************************************************************/

var MC = {};

/**
 **  Object Pipe
 */

MC.o_p = {
    model  :  'default',
    result :  'continue',
    page   :  {},
    args   :  {},
    server :  {},
    hash   :  localStorage.hash
};
```

I thought about doing something like this:

```
MC.o_p1 = function() {
    return {
        model  :  'default',
        result :  'continue',
        page   :  {},
        args   :  {},
        server :  {},
        hash   :  localStorage.hash
        }
}
```

but now the return object is in local scope to whatever called it.

I need global instance based objects.

I'm not sure if I'm over thinking this or what I'm asking is possible?

Answer (score 3):

Hold your package **privately** and just have some access functions:

```
var myModel = (function() {

    var model_vars = {
        model: 'default',
        result: 'continue',
        page: {},
        args: {},
        server: {},
        hash: localStorage.hash
    };

    return function() {
        this.get = function(ele) {
            if (model_vars.hasOwnProperty(ele)) {
                return model_vars[ele];
            }

        };

        this.set = function(ele, value) {
            if (model_vars.hasOwnProperty(ele)) {
                return model_vars[ele] = value;
            }

        };

    };

})();
```

Then you can just do:

```
Model = new myModel();
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/PSsQ3/

Comment: so each "ele" is an object pipe with a value "value"?

Comment: @HiroProtagonist I updated my answer. What do you mean by "object pipe"?

Comment: sorry...how many model_vars are there here...I don't think you can have more than one b.c. you put it in a module pattern....

Comment: @HiroProtagonist See the demo I added.

Comment: anyways...can you make multiple instances...with this....there can only be one...b.c. it is module pattern?

Comment: there is only one 'var model_vars' at any given time

Comment: This is the registry pattern sort of.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass in the global scope and use it when you need it, something like this:

```
MC.o_p1 = function(global) {
    return {
        model  :  'default',
        result :  'continue',
        page   :  {},
        args   :  {},
        server :  {},
        hash   :  global.localStorage.hash
        }
}(window);
```

Comment: How does that effect the one line return statement?

Comment: window is global in browsers -- oh wait is this node.js?

Comment: @HiroProtagonist - it does not -- the function is called before it is assigned.

Comment: so the return statement will still go to what called it....how do I pop these objects out into the global space?

Comment: is it possible to do such a thing?

Comment: This works exactly like your "static" version.  Except every time you want to access the global space inside the creation of `o_p1` you prefix with `global.`  You could also modify this to cache the object and then if it has already been created return the cached item instead of the new one.

Comment: MC.o_p1 should already have access to the window object...you just optimized it using global import.

Comment: What exactly is your question?  You complained about not having the global namespace available -- I showed you how to pass it in to your creation and make global access explicit (all good things).  Now you say I was optimizing - which I wasn't.  What exactly are you trying to do that my answer or Neal's does not solve?

Answer (score 1):

```
var msg = 'window is global in browsers';

window.alert(msg);

alert('or we can just use alert without accessing from window because, '+msg);

function isWindowReallyGlobalInBrowsers(){
    window.newMsg = 'Did you see var newMsg get declared anywhere?';
    alert(newMsg + ' It works because ' +msg);
}

isWindowReallyGlobalInBrowsers();
```

Try it in a browser console. Ask questions as needed.

Comment: Assigning as a property of window makes it global in any context. And yes, msg was defined in the global context so it's accessible from anywhere. You could alert window.msg and get msg.

Comment: JS is not only not block-scoped but it's function/constructor scoped and everything from parent context is accessible to an inner function. You can alter stuff in an outer-scope.